# nesting JSF Expressionlanguage and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, onclick, el, nested

I may have the wrong idea of the relation of the JSF expression language to javaScript.
What I'm trying to do is nesting a bit of JSF EL in js in JSF EL. Which should look something like this:

```
<h:commandLink onclick="#{ condition ? 'jsFunction('#{bean.property}delimiter#{bean.prop2}')' :''}" action="...
```

obviously this does not work, so how do you nest a bit of JSF EL in js in JSF EL?

ps.: I know I could make two commandlinks and move the condition into the "rendered" attribute but I want to understand the relation of this conjunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't nest EL expressions nor concatenate strings in EL expressions. You've also a JS syntax error by closing the function call with `}` instead of `)`.

Prepare the nested expression beforehand with `<c:set>` wherein you can just inline the desired expression in the resultant string value:

```
<c:set var="jsFunction" value="jsFunction('#{bean.property}delimiter#{bean.prop2}')" />
```

This way you can just print it as follows:

```
<h:commandLink ... onclick="#{condition ? jsFunction : ''}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.
The JS syntax error was a typo, not part of the problem in question.